# export an aerial image to .SID file and a .Tiff file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, geotiff-tiff, aerial-photography, mrsid

I am using arcmap 10.4.1 ( also have PRO 2.0 is this is an valid option)

I have an aerial image that was broken down to small grids and need to export each grid to a .sid file and a .tiff file. I cannot find a tool that supports both of these file types.

Can this be done in arcmap or do I need another software?

Comment: With "Raster to Other Format tool" in ArcGIS you can convert to "tiff" .If you have many rasters, use batch for this tool.You can't export raster to MrSID in ArcGIS: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010982

Comment: are you aware of any other methods to export it to .SID files? a co-worker wants to use this aerial inside his AutoCAD software

Comment: If you have licence of FME software, Use it to convert. there are some softwares and libraries like  gdal .

Comment: sid is a proprietary technology from Lizard Tech. They will be happy to sell you their software.  You might check with your co-worker to see if a jpeg 2000 (jp2) version will be okay; it is similar wavelet compression technology.  You can use ArcGIS to create jp2 files.